# how to modularise a menu driven code in java

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, modularity

In java  How can I modularise code in which there is a main method containing objects of array and then a switch case to take input for suppose Customer and later using that switch case to display .for entering the inputs like id, name, address etc in . how can I move these codes ?